# Override Show Overload Due to Subtyping

Tags: arrays, julia

I have

```
type MyArray{T,N} <: AbstractArray{T,N}
  x::Array{T,N}
  y::Int
end
```

It prints like an array. However, I would like its show/print/display/Juno render to act like it's just any ol' type. Is there a good way to remove the overrides without dropping the `AbstractArray` subtyping?

Comment: Why can't you just override its display method?

Comment: With what would I override it with to get the standard type display back?

Comment: you mean like: `julia> show(a::MyArray) = print("MyArray($(a.x), $(a.y))");
` ? (I know what you mean though. You don't want to 'emulate' it for this particular case, you want to restore it in general)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to restore the standard `Base.show` behavior for a type, using `invoke`:

```
julia> type MyArray{T,N} <: AbstractArray{T,N}
         x::Array{T,N}
         y::Int
       end

julia> Base.show(io::IO, A::MyArray) =
           invoke(show, Tuple{typeof(io), Any}, io, A)

julia> Base.show(io::IO, ::MIME"text/plain", A::MyArray) = show(io, A)

julia> MyArray([1, 2, 3], 4)
MyArray{Int64,1}([1, 2, 3], 4)
```

I don't know if this handles the Juno part; apparently Juno uses its own infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how one might generically 'restore' the default `show` function, but this is easy enough to emulate:

```julia
julia> type MyArray{T,N} <: AbstractArray{T,N}
         x::Array{T,N}
         y::Int
       end

julia> Base.show(io::IO, a::MyArray) = print(io, "$(typeof(a))($(a.x), $(a.y))");
julia> Base.show(io::IO, ::MIME"text/plain", a::MyArray) = show(io, a);

julia> a = MyArray([1., 2., 3., 4., 5.], 5)
MyArray{Float64,1}([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0], 5)
```

---

As an aside, personally I find `dump` to work a lot better as a multi-line 'display' function than the default one for such an array-containing type:

```julia
julia> Base.show(io::IO, ::MIME"text/plain", a::MyArray) = dump(a);

julia> a
MyArray{Float64,1}
  x: Array{Float64}((5,)) [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
  y: Int64 5
```

Comment: But does that fix the Juno printing? I don't think it does.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas I don't use Juno myself, but I suspect you'd have to do something like this: http://discuss.junolab.org/t/base-show-not-called-in-juno/931